# Magento 2 Admin user can't access Admin menus

Tags: admin, permissions, csp

I have a Magento 2.4.1 admin instance, I have created a Admin user through command line,
But am able to login but cant access anything. how to to add this permission to admin user.
[image]

I cant access these Menus. How to fix this. Can I get help.? thank you in advance.

Comment: as per screen shot, you need to change current password. it seems existing password is expired!

Comment: @Pawan Thank you for response I just showing that screen shot for reference. Password is working fine, its able to login

Answer (score 0):

You have to create `User Roles` and then assign those roles to any user you want. Go to `System->User Roles->Add New Role` and then `Role Resources` on left and Select what roles you want to assign to your new user. Then go to `System->All Users` and add your new user or edit existing one. In left side click on `User Role` and assign it to the user. Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you for Helping @Abdul Samad Abbasi, but am not able to access `System`. except `Dashboard` nothing is able to click

Comment: I'm not sure but you can try running [these](https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-2-x-Admin-Configuration/Magento-2-3-Buttons-in-Admin-Menu-are-inactive-not-clickable/td-p/124713) commands.

Comment: Yes I did, but same not clickable

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot click any of the menu items in the left hand (dark gray) icons, this happened to us when we had turned on JS minification and/or merging.  Try disabling those.